# Is there a reason my singleton instantiates only when referenced? How can I make it instantiate when my app launches?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

```
class TheOneAndOnlyKraken {
    static let sharedInstance = TheOneAndOnlyKraken()
}
```

This is the blue print of the singleton I implemented. I use my singleton in order to get the user's location throughout all of the project files, and the issue is that in the first time I get that information is returns nil (because it needs a second to setup I guess). This is why I'm interested in instantiating the singleton as soon as the app launches, to avoid working with nil location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not call your singleton in **AppDelegate**:

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        _ = TheOneAndOnlyKraken.sharedInstance
        return true
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Can you explain why this happens though? Isn't it what the keyword "lazy" is about?

Comment: Yes, it's like "lazy" keywords, here is an article for your reference: https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton